# About an inequality using $\ln \ln n$ related to Robin's inequality.

Tags: analysis, number-theory, inequality

Is $\ln\ln n < \sigma(n)/n$, where $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of the divisors of $n$? Or is this grossly innacurate or too vague?

Comment: This site is full of people that is willing to spend their time helping you and answering your questions. The least you can do is to write a clear question with all the background needed, since if you don't people will almost surely ignore your question. Also, $\LaTeX$ typesetting is recommended.

Comment: What do you mean by $\sum n$?

Comment: Why didn't you clarify that $\sigma (n)$ is the function that returns the sum of all the divisors of $n$? That is what I mean, you just wrote unclear things, you need to say what is $\sigma$, and anything you use in your questions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma#Lower-case

Comment: It's rather dangerous to make assertions about what is "clear to most mathematicians", and my best advice is to avoid such assertions. On the other hand, it is always best on an anonymous site like this one, with mathematicians of many, many different backgrounds, to be as clear as possible when you write your question.

Comment: If the level of detail needed is unclear, feedback from users like @AlbertoDebernardi should be helpful to you, and my best advice here is not to denigrate such users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality should hold for infinitely many $n$ because of Gronwall's theorem. This states that $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sigma(n)}{n \ln \ln n} = e^\gamma$$

This means that there are infinitely many $n$ such that $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n \ln \ln n}$ is close to $e^\gamma$.

However, for most $n$ it isn't true that $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}>\ln \ln n$. For example, there are no prime powers bigger than 1618 that can statistify that.

I have calculated that there are exactly:

- 12,116 numbers below 100,000 that statistify $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}>\ln \ln n$
- 2,017 numbers below 10,000 that statistify $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}>\ln \ln n$.
- 372 numbers below 1,000 that statistify $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}>\ln \ln n$.

Answer (score 2):

If $n$ is prime, the right hand side is $(n+1)/n$ (which in particular is less than $3/2$), but the left hand side can be as large as we like.

Comment: If n is a counterexample to Robin's inequality then the (sum of all the divisors of n) /n > e^(gamma) lnln(n) > inin(n). So the inequality is true if n is a counterexample to Robin's inequality and Riemann's Hypothesis..

Comment: Is lnln(n) > 7/4 ((sum of all the divisors of n)/n) ? Forgive notation.

Comment: Is lnln(n) > 7/4 ( {'sigma'}(n)/n) ;( forgive notation)?